# How are user-defined delegates used and created in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I've used delegates when designing win forms in .NET... i.e. drag/drop a button, double click, and fill in the myButton_click event.  I want to understand how to create and use user-defined delegates in C#.

How are user-defined delegates used and created in C# ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest reading a tutorial on the topic.

Basically, you declare a delegate type:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(string message);
```

Then you can either assign and call it directly:

```
MyDelegate = SomeFunction;
MyDelegate("Hello, bunny");
```

Or you create an event:

```
public event MyDelegate MyEvent;
```

Then you can add an event handler from outside like this:

```
SomeObject.MyEvent += SomeFunction;
```

Visual Studio is helpful with this. After you entered the +=, just press tab-tab and it will create the handler for you.

Then you can fire the event from inside the object:

```
if (MyEvent != null) {
    MyEvent("Hello, bunny");
}
```

That's the basic usage.

Comment: +1, you just forgot the "delegate" keyword on first code line.

Answer (score 1):

```
public delegate void testDelegate(string s, int i);

private void callDelegate()
{
    testDelegate td = new testDelegate(Test);

    td.Invoke("my text", 1);
}

private void Test(string s, int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a duplicate (can't find a duplicate) but lots of information here on SO, try

[Differnce between Events and Delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563549/difference-between-events-and-delegates-and-its-respective-applications) to get started, then look at

[When to use . . .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491374/c-can-someone-tell-me-why-and-where-i-should-use-delegates)

[What are Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net)

[Whis is this delegate doing . . .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73024/what-is-this-delegate-call-doing-in-this-line-of-code-c)

Hope these help

Answer (score 1):

For broad answer check this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NETDelegatesAndEvents.aspx#Definition) by [mohamad halabi](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=3651361). 
For shorter answer check this slightly modified example from the c:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Samples/1033/ folder ...

```
using System;
using System.IO; 


namespace DelegateExample
{
  class Program
  {
    public delegate void PrintDelegate ( string s );

    public static void Main ()
    {
      PrintDelegate delFileWriter = new PrintDelegate ( PrintFoFile );
      PrintDelegate delConsoleWriter = new PrintDelegate ( PrintToConsole);
      Console.WriteLine ( "PRINT FIRST TO FILE by passing the print delegate -- DisplayMethod ( delFileWriter )" );

      DisplayMethod ( delFileWriter );      //prints to file
      Console.WriteLine ( "PRINT SECOND TO CONSOLE by passing the print delegate -- DisplayMethod ( delConsoleWriter )" );
      DisplayMethod ( delConsoleWriter ); //prints to the console
      Console.WriteLine ( "Press enter to exit" );
      Console.ReadLine ();

    }

    static void PrintFoFile ( string s )
    {
      StreamWriter objStreamWriter = File.CreateText( AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() + "file.txt" );
      objStreamWriter.WriteLine ( s );
      objStreamWriter.Flush ();
      objStreamWriter.Close ();
    }


    public static void DisplayMethod ( PrintDelegate delPrintingMethod )
    { 
      delPrintingMethod( "The stuff to print regardless of where it will go to" ) ;
    }

    static void PrintToConsole ( string s )
    {
      Console.WriteLine ( s );    
    } //eof method 
  } //eof classs 
} //eof namespace
```