# How would I convert C# delegate function to VB.Net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73024/what-is-this-delegate-call-doing-in-this-line-of-code-c)  there's an old question about this code.

```
xmpp.OnLogin += delegate(object o) 
                { 
                    xmpp.Send(
                        new Message(
                            new Jid(JID_RECEIVER),
                            MessageType.chat, 
                            "Hello, how are you?"
                        )
                    );
                };
```

I want to use it in vb.net (version 10) but I couldn't figure out how to convert it.

Comment: What part are you having troubles with ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delegate is an anonymous function. The syntax is a bit different for VB .NET, as expected. Without having the VB compiler at hand, I would say you need something like:

```
AddHandler xmpp.OnLogin,
    Sub(o As Object)
        xmpp.Send(
                    new Message(
                        new Jid(JID_RECEIVER),
                        MessageType.chat, 
                        "Hello, how are you?"
                    )
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think VB.net will like the `;` you left there unless things have changed recently and I didn't know ;)

Comment: it works! (i removed the ; no big deal...) Thank you very much

Comment: @Icarus, it doesn't like it obviously ;-) (fixed)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how to declare an anonymous delegate in VB.NET and I'm too lazy to Google it, but something like this should work (warning: not tested):

```
AddHandler xmpp.OnLogin, AddressOf Me.HandleSendMessage

Private Sub HandleSendMessage(ByVal o As Object)
xmpp.Send( new Message(
               new Jid(JID_RECEIVER),
                            MessageType.chat, 
                            "Hello, how are you?"
                        )
                    )
End Sub
```